# Hipervínculo a otro JavaScript con valores

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

Estoy intentando hacer un calendario con js, html y css. Ya lo tengo finalizado, ahora me falta que al pulsar sobre un día me lleve a otro javascript dentro de la misma web, y que recoja el año y mes sobre el que he pulsado. Lo estoy intentando con :
 `<a href='javascript:select_pordias(+year+, +meses[month-1]+, +dia+);'>` , pero no me lo pilla, y tampoco sé si lo estoy haciendo bien para que me lleve a ese javascript.

Necesitaría que el link fuera a la misma web pero a otro javascript que tengo con el nombre de select_pordias. Os dejo el link a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr>";
 
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);
 var a=0;
 var b= ++a;
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // celda mes anterior y siguiente
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'><a href='#'>"+(ultimoDiaMes - (primerDiaSemana - i - 1))+"</a></td>";
  } else if (i>=last_cell) {
  if (i % 7 == 0) {
                  resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #fd9292'><a href='javascript:select_pordias(+year+, +meses[month-1]+, +dia+);'>"+a+++"</a></td>";
                  } else {
                    resultado+="<td class='post' style='color: #cccccc'><a href='#'>"+a+++"</a></td>";
                  }
      }
   else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy' ><a href='#'>"+dia+"</a></td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td><a href='#'>"+dia+"</a></td>";
   dia++;
  }
  
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="<tr></tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";
 
 
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
 

 
 // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month]= meses[0];
 }
  if(month+1>12)
 {
 meses[month+1]= meses[1];
 }
  if (month >=11 && month <12){
  meses[month]= meses[11];
  meses[month+1]= meses[0];
  }
 if(month-1<1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[11];
 meses[month-3]=meses[10];
 }
  if(month-1 >0 && month-1 <=1){
 meses[month-2]=meses[0];
 meses[month-3]=meses[11];
 }
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #calendar {
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  #calendar caption {
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background-color:white;
   
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:medium;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   
  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) { display: inline; margin-top: 5px; width: 20%;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) {text-align: left; float: left; color: #cccccc; }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) {text-align: right; float: right; color: #cccccc;  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(5) { float: left; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(6) { float: right; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(7) { float: left;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(8) { float: right;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar th {
   background-color:white;
   padding: 22px;
   width:40px;
   
  }
  #calendar td {
   text-align:center;
   padding:2px 5px;
   background-color:white;
   font-size:20px;
  }
  #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }
  #calendar .hoy {
   background-color:grey;
  }
  #calendar .ayer {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post {
   color: #cccccc;
   }
  #calendar .post:nth-child(DOMINGO){
  color:blue;}

 </style>
 
</head>
 
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una aclaración @JoumeParra , java y javascript o es lo mismo, te lo digo para que no tengas mal entendidos en la pregunta, editala.Saludos.

Comment: Si, error mio, gracias por la sugerencia no me habia dado cuenta. Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, quieres acceder a otro archivo *.js  que contiene la funcion select_pordias() ?

Comment: Puedes hacer una variable global fuera de los scripts para que ambos tomen el mismo valor. U otra almacenando en un localstorage, cookie o algo parecido el valor de la variable para después utilizarlo.

Comment: Así es, @gmarsi

Comment: Algo así me gustaría que me ayudaran a hacerlo, no sé de que forma ponerlo... @Cig

Comment: Para acceder a otros scripts dentro de la misma pagina importalo en la misma pagina HTML. <script src="scriptSelectPorDias.js"></script> <script src="scriptMostrarCalendario.js"></script>

Con esto podras acceder a las variables del script, no se si me explico

Comment: El problema está en la misma formulación de la pregunta. No se navega a "otro javascript", te podrán llevar (o no) a otra URL, o podrás ejecutar un nuevo script, o llamar una función de un script que no habías llamado. Pero no te llevan a "otro script".

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de poner los scripts debes de hacerlo de forma que al que quieras acceder se haya cargado primero que desde el que accedes.

Suponganos que tienes tu HTML e indicas los scripts que vas a usar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Tu codigo -->
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script1.js seria el archivo donde se encuantra la funcion **select_pordias()** mientras que el archivo script2.js seria donde tienes la funcion **mostrarCalendario()**. Para mostrarlo de forma facil imagina lo siguiente

en script1.js tienes una variable

```
var saludo = 'Hola'
```

y en script2.js tienes

```
console.log(saludo)
```

Al ejecutarlo veras que se muestra correctamente ''Hola'' por consola. Si pones los scripts del reves te saldra un error ya que no puedes acceder a una variable que aun no se ha declarado

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero no seria en script1 el mostrarCalendario() para poder recojer la variable del mes, año y dia que quiero ver, y luego imprimirlo en select_pordias? Aparte de eso me ha servido para poder enganchar los dos javascript, pero me gustaria saber cómo guardar la variable en mostrarCalendario() y luego supongo que en select_pordias() deberé poner console.log(variableguardada), no?