# Como redirigir datos a otro javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, ajax

Os cuento, tengo un proyecto de calendario, agenda, de forma que esta "indexado" en un archivo body_agenda.php, la cual determina unos botones superiores que si pulsas uno pasas al calendario por semanas, si pulsas otro al de por días...

Pues bueno, lo que quiero es que al pulsar un día del calendario por semanas, me lleve al calendario por días y me muestre el día que he pulsado.

El calendario por semanas es un php, el calendario por días es otro php, y están unidos por así decirlo por un js. Lo que no sé es cómo hacer que al pulsar pase eso, ya que con lo que tengo, me lleva al pordias.php, pero claro, yo no quiero que cambie de página, quiero que se quede en la misma página usando el js. Lo que estaba intentando es lo siguiente:

```js
function guardardia(dia, anio, mes){
    var fecha = "El dia es: "+dia+ " El mes: "+mes+" El año: "+anio;
    location.href ="javascript:select_pordias()"; //No se si es correcto
    localStorage.setItem('fecha', JSON.stringify(fecha));

}
function recogerdia(){
    var fecha = localStorage.getItem('fecha');
    document.getElementById('fecha').innerHTML = fecha;
}
```

Y luego en la página de php pordias:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="recogerdia()">
    <div id="fecha"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/semanal.js"></script>
</html>
```

Pero me lleva al javascript pordias, pero se queda en blanco...no me sale la info. Por eso no sé si location.href a un javascript es correcto. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Ya te respondieron  en esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171612/pasar-distintas-variables-javascript-html-al-clickar y en otras de días anteriores te han dado otras respuestas excelentes. Creo que deberías ya contratar a alguno de los programadores que te han respondido para que terminen de hacer tu ejercicio.

Comment: Te sugerimos realizar una pregunta en lugar de varias que están relacionadas a la misma pregunta, pero que esta pregunta sea basada en [ask] @JourneParra Te aseguro que de esta forma obtendrías la ayuda requerida, saludos!